# Email links don't automatically switch to Opera

Tags: thunderbird, email, opera

Swapped to Opera because Firefox is currently very buggy (and slower).  However, although I've got Opera set as default browser, and clicking on a link in Thunderbird opens the link in Opera, the system doesn't automatically switch to Opera, as it did to Firefox when that's set as the default browser.

Anyone know how to get auto-switching to Opera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the command below in a terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

and select `/usr/bin/opera`

---

*Example*

```
% sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
There are 3 choices for the alternative x-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/x-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-beta   150       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/firefox              40        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/google-chrome-beta   150       manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/opera                120       manual mode
```

---

Check the default applications your system settings:

<kbd>System Settings > Details > Default Applications</kbd>

and select <kbd>Opera</kbd>

Comment: @bipco As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this - this has partially fixed it.  If Opera is closed and I click on a link it opens the browser and switches to it.  If it's already open then _some_ links automatically switch, and some open a new tab but don't switch to it.  So better than before though not 100%.